# How do I extract the range of values for each row between two vectors?

Tags: r, vector

I am trying to get the range of values for each row between two vectors in a single output vector. So, if the data I'm working with are:

```
v1<-c(1,2,3)
v2<-c(4,5,6)
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6
```

which is basically:

```
c(1:4, 2:5, 3:6)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` to get the sequence (`:`) of corresponding elements of both vectors and then `unlist` the `list` output

```
unlist(Map(`:`, v1, v2))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
out <- c()
for(i in seq_along(v1)) out <- c(out, v1[i]:v2[i])
```